# jQuery: Menu item sliding slightly to the right when mouseover

Tags: jquery, menu, sliding

I assume this is an easy one to make, but I'm not really used to jQuery yet, I've just started to learn.

By CSS, we can write a item:hover class and write left:20px; to apply a slight sliding effect to our menu items e.g `<li> Item </li>`

Now I want to achieve this in smooth action, namely not appearing suddenly at 20 pixels right but sliding to there. I think animate thing in jQuery is used for such animations, but I'm really bad at jQuery, I don't know where to and in what order I should put the codes. Can you give me a quick example of this? :)

Comment: you can do that with css animation also; won't work on old browser but old browser users would not probably even notice this so who cares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
 $('li').hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({left:20},2000)
  },function(){
      $(this).animate({left:0},2000)
 });
```

this will animate all the `<li>` present in the document.. you can give a class to `<li>` to be specific.. `2000` is the duration of the animation here

Comment: you need to use  jQuery.Color() plugin to animate the color..  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery as pointed out in bipen's answer.

I have some simple CSS for handling hover transitions but as said by mikakun, this will only work for browsers CSS3 check out [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) for compatible browsers.

```
li {
    /* put your base styles here */
}

li:hover {
    /* put your new styles here */
    transition:all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition:all 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition:all 300ms ease;
}
```

This will put a 300ms transition for whatever you specify for the particular elements.

You can see this in action if you have a CSS3 compatible browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/7aRhe/